# Filter results from QueryDSL search

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I'm using QueryDSL as part of Spring Data Rest to search entities from our API.

Is it possible to somehow filter the search API, so that by default it won't find for example Car entities that are "deactivated"?

Currently I've a flag on car entity that when it's set to true, it shouldn't be exposed through our search API, and the cars that have this property set should be left out from search.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - please provide some code (a sample of your domain object, repository and any relevant code sample), an input query and the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case of using Spring Data REST and QueryDSL, to change standard behavior of queries we can use aspects.

For example: we need to show by default only those `Model`s whose `flag` is set to `true`:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Model {

    @Id @GeneratedValue private Integer id;
    @NotBlank private String name;
    private boolean flag;
}
```

In this case we implement the aspect like this:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelRepoAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.ModelRepo.findAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate, org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable))")
  public void modelFindAllWithPredicateAndPageable() {
  }

  @Around("modelFindAllWithPredicateAndPageable()")
  public Object filterModelsByFlag(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    Predicate predicate = (Predicate) args[0];

    BooleanExpression flagIsTrue = QModel.model.flag.eq(true);

    if (predicate == null) {
        args[0] = flagIsTrue;
    } else {
        if (!predicate.toString().contains("model.flag")) {
            args[0] = flagIsTrue.and(predicate);
        }
    }

    return pjp.proceed(args);
  }
}
```

This aspect intercepts all calls of method `findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable)` of our repo, and add the filter `model.flag = true` to the query if the request parameters was not set (`predicate == null`), or if they don't contain 'flag' parameter. Otherwise aspect does not modify original `predicate`.

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty much what I wanted. I'll have to test it out, but the logic seems to be exactly what I was looking for. 

I'll mark your answer accept as soon as I've tried it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Since QueryDslPredicateExecutor doesn't offer a way to access the final predicate and Spring Security PostFilter doesn't work on pageable, this is literally the only way to filter the results from a QueryDSL repo. Thank you !