# Add dynamic behavior to Spring's JpaRepository based on traits applied to entities

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data, traits

I have a huge legacy database that contains hundred of tables. Some of them contains a common behavior: a subset will have a couple of date columns that define the validity range of a row, some other tables would define a special 'is enabled' flag column, another subset will have a label feature (key + string values).

These tables are mapped to Java with Spring-Data 2.0.8.

From the code perspective it would make sens to have 'traits' that can be added to the entities, like HasDateRange, HasEnableFlag or HasLabel to let the code works on these abstractions.

For example, I would like to have a special Repository that extends the JpaRepository interface and add to each request a predicate about the startDate and endDate to restrict the scope to the entities where the time range is valid for today.

These tables are mapped to Java with Spring-Data 2.0.8.

**Is it possible to decorate the associated JPA repositories so the generated queries are "automagically" modified on the fly to match the trait ?**

Comment: Please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48843827) - maybe it can be helpful...

Comment: yes, it looks exactly like what I want to achieve. I'll try to implement it this way and will put answer here if I manage to configure my repo with AOC.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @Cepr0 the solution is a good proposal, but I'm not sure that's will be such a good idea: there's too much way to get the query, sometime buried in private method... So it will be error prone and hard to debug. I'll try to find something else.